# Using await inside typescript void function

Tags: typescript

I have an interface with a method that returns void and I'd like the implementations could be sync or async, but since the interface returns void, I can't use `await` keyword and I wouldn't like to use promise.
Anybody has any alternative?
Here is a simple code that express what I'm asking (the commented code is what I want to use).

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-kowalevski-c0i31

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you share the code you have tried so far in the question.

Comment: It's a language requirement: you either use `await` and make a function `async` + returning a `Promise<T>`; or use promises explicitly.

Comment: @MikePoole I've put a simple example on codesandox https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-kowalevski-c0i31

Answer (score 0):

Prefix `foo` with async like so:

```
class AsyncVoidImpl implements VoidInterface {
  async foo() {
    const response = await doAsyncTask()
    console.log(response)
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because when I add `async`, typescript implies that I return a`Promise<void>` and it doesn't fits the interface that returns `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since I don't care about the return value of the function simply because I'll not use it, I added `any` to return type on interface insteade of `void` and now It doesn't matter if I return a Promise at the implementation or doesn't return nothing.